# move the div according to window scrollbar

Tags: html, css, positioning

I want to move my div down  if my window scroll down and move up on window scrolls up? How to implement?

Answer (score 7):

```
<div style="position:fixed;">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

> **position:fixed**
>
> Generates an absolutely positioned element, positioned relative to the browser window. The element's position is specified with the "left", "top", "right", and "bottom" properties.
>
> Source: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Note that IE6 does not support position fixed.

Comment: Note also IE6 does not support fun.

Comment: Be aware that there are compatibility issues with position: fixed in "certain" browsers.  See here for some work-arounds: http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS to do this.

```
<div style="position:fixed">
```